# narrow situation but broad answer - closing useful?

Tags: discussion

I admit in advance: This egoisticly motivated: I do not consider the question a good one (relevant information missing, no research effort recognizable) I just got into a bad mood because I like my answer (and was thinking about better approaches for the case that the asker was going to try this) and now I had to realize that the question got closed:

[Can I recover data from a RAID5 after accidental changed of disk order?](https://serverfault.com/questions/496982/can-i-recover-data-from-a-raid5-after-accidental-changed-of-disk-order/497030)

I can accept that problems with a certain hardware (related to that hardware in that sense that either the problem cannot occur with other products or that the solution is not usable for other products) are considered as too narrow and closed but does that make sense if an answer offers (or at least tries to) a generic approach?

Obviously you can create disk order problems with many controllers. I don't know though whether other ones are stupid enough to result in such failure. But the question title is broad and the answer is broad. So why should this one not be of use for later users searching for the problem?

Answer (score 5):

Personally, if an answer actually supplies a generally useful solution to what seems an overly broad or too narrowly scoped question, I'm in favor of keeping it. It's all google-bait in the end.

Answer (score 3):

Because your answer is a generally good one I don't really have a problem with leaving this around as a *closed* question (i.e. I wouldn't vote to delete it), but I don't personally think the question worth reopening -- It doesn't meet the general standard for good-quality questions on Server Fault because it's so vague, and it probably won't get any better answers than what it already has.

Right now unless enough users vote to either reopen or delete the question it will pretty much stay forever in this "closed but answered" state (and people can vote on the question / answers if they want to). If you want to improve your current answer & add more info you certainly can (the system will let you edit answers on closed questions), it just prevents any new answers from being added unless the question gets improved.

Answer (score 1):

You could redo the question for OP, to make it broader/easier to find...